# Format json SQL using Replace command

Tags: json, sql-server, string, geospatial, geojson

I want to change the format from r1 to r2 Using SQL Server

r1 :[  [  [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],  [ 3, 3 ],[ 4, 4 ]  ]  ]

r2 (should be ) : (1 1, 2 2), (3 3, 4 4)

ps: the r1 is a JSON coordinates (multilinestring) that this format is exactly stored in SQL.. the number that I put just for reduce the confusion,

My code

```
 declare @r1 varchar(max)= '[  [  [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],  [ 3, 3 ],[ 4, 4 ]  ]  ]'
declare @r2 varchar(max) = replace(replace(replace(@r1,' ',''), '[','('), ']',')')
select @r2
```

the result doesn't give me the format that I need.

Comment: Why do you replace spaces, if your "should be" keep them? Maybe you should remove `'[ '` and `' ]'`

Answer (score 2):

If you have valid JSON, you should use JSON functions to parse it

```
DECLARE @r1 nvarchar(max) = N'[ [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 3 ],[ 4, 4 ] ] ]';

SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
  '(',
  JSON_VALUE(value, '$[0]'),
  ' ',
  JSON_VALUE(value, '$[1]'),
  ', ',
  JSON_VALUE(nextValue, '$[0]'),
  ' ',
  JSON_VALUE(nextValue, '$[1]'),
  ')'
  ), ', ')
FROM (
    SELECT
      j2.[key],
      j2.value,
      nextValue = LEAD(j2.value) OVER (ORDER BY j2.[key])
    FROM OPENJSON(@r1) j1
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
) j
WHERE CAST([key] AS int) % 2 = 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=acf3813c7402c60d3257674533db4697)